# Ftp Form - Could i add a progress bar or stat bar for the file upload?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, ftp

I was wondering could i add  a progress bar or stat bar for the file upload to this code below?

ftp form:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style4 {font-size: x-small}
.style6 {font-size: xx-small}
.style7 {font-size: x-small; color: #000000; }
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>
<code> <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="post">
  <p><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000000000" />
    <br>
Send this file:</p>
  <p>
  <input name="userfile" type="file" />
  </p>
  <p><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
    <br>
  </p>
</form></code>

 -->
</body>
</html>
```

the php file:

```
<?php
// In PHP versions earlier than 4.1.0, $HTTP_POST_FILES should be used instead
// of $_FILES.  In PHP versions earlier than 4.0.3, use copy() and
// is_uploaded_file() instead of move_uploaded_file.
$ftp_server = "tttt";
$ftp_user = "ttt";
$ftp_pass = "tt";

// set up a connection or die
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server");

// try to login
if (@ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass)) {
echo "Connected as $ftp_user@$ftp_server\n";
} else {
echo "Couldn't connect as $ftp_user\n";
}

$remote_file = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];;
//I used these for debugging
echo $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
echo "<br>";
echo $_FILES['userfile']['type'];
echo "<br>";
echo $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
echo "<br>";
echo $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
echo "<br>";
echo $_FILES['userfile']['error'];
echo "<br>";

//v important this one as you have to use the tmp_file created for the actual upload
$file = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_BINARY)) {
echo "successfully uploaded $file\n";
} else {
echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
}

// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

could i add  a progress bar or stat bar for the file upload to this code below?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot get the progress of a file using php. Wordpress has a progress indicator but I know that they load the image into a flash movie and display the progress via that.

Comment: OK, thank you. could you suggest me flash or ajax examples with using php's ftp function

Comment: ftp_ functions do not send any status, what I could see you doing is faking it out and downloading the image to get the downloaded bytes and total bytes, or taking the filesize and dividing it by the connection speed. Either way you won't be able to get an accurate progress bar. My suggestion is to just use a spinny loader to show when the download starts and hide when it is complete

Comment: i would like to upload large files (2GB+). Browser based upoad methods can't allow this. For this reason i chosed to use php's ftp function. Do have you any alternative suggest for solving this issue?

Comment: Theres a setting in the php.ini file which specifies the maxupload size. I just pulled a ini file for php 4 and its on line 597 but just do a search for upload_max_filesize and change it to 2000M